# Google Sheets - Invoice numbers

Tags: function, google-sheets

I do invoices for my clients in Google sheets.

I now need to include a unique "invoice number" on each new invoice created.

Currently I have one invoice per sheet and I create new invoices by "duplicating" the most recent sheet.

So essentially 2 questions:

1) Can I arrange so that which I create a new invoice, the `invoice no` cell will automatically increment?

2) Can I make an invoice number that is based on the date range of the week that the invoice was created.   eg `"Week of 10/15/18 - 10/19/18"` would become : `101518101918`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Both options 1 and 2 can be done easily, but we would need to see what you mean by "duplicating" exactly.  Also on this site you are expected to show what you have tried and maybe also provide a link to a test sheet. Then you are much more likely to get a considered rely.

Comment: Hey bcperth - thank you for the tips, I am new here and I'll try to do better going forward.

Comment: By duplicating, I mean... I have one "workbook" for all of my invoices for a school. I right-click on last-week's "sheet" (tabs on the bottom), and select "duplicate" to create next week's sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily using the `"Duplicate"` function.

You need to make a new sheet to control the generation of new invoices. This sheet would contain the last used `invoice number`, and a `button` to create a new sheet.

When you click the `button`, this would fire a `script` to make a new sheet and copy the cells from the previous invoice and increment the `invoice number` cell.

This is not very complicated if you are familiar with Google scripts. If not you need to do some tutorials or otherwise seek assistance. This is not a good site to ask people to write code, but you can certainly get help here if your code is not working as you expect.